# Flex trying to replace a loaded SWF with another throws illegal override even after unloading first

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

If I load two swfs one after the other it throws me an error illegal override. The first swf is compiled with SDK 4.7 and the second with SDK 3.5. I have tried to load them separately and they both work. But sequencially and after removing the first one it throws Error #1053: Illegal override of activate in mx.managers.SystemManagerProxy.

```
public function App()
    {
        _fs.open(_installerDownloader,FileMode.READ);
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        _fs.readBytes(ba);
        _fs.close();

        context = new LoaderContext();
        context.allowCodeImport = true;
        context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

        loader = new Loader();
        this.addChild(loader); //required so that the loaded SWF has access to the 'stage' property
        loader.loadBytes(ba,context); //run the loaded SWF within the security sandbox of this application
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    }

    public function launchApplication():void
    {   
        loader.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,launchMC);
        loader.unloadAndStop(true);
        this.removeChild(loader);
    }

    public function launchMC(e:Event):void
    {
        _fs.open(_installer,FileMode.READ);
        var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        _fs.readBytes(ba);
        _fs.close();            

        context = new LoaderContext();
        context.allowCodeImport = true;
        context.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
        loader = new Loader();
        this.addChild(loader); //required so that the loaded SWF has access to the 'stage' property
        loader.loadBytes(ba,context); //run the loaded SWF within the security sandbox of this application
        stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
        stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    }
```

Thanks,
David

Comment: For a workaround, if you use SWFLoader instead of Loader, loadForCompability set to true should work. 
For reference [Loading applications with the SWFLoader control](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf619ab-7ff0.html)

Comment: Its an actionscript project and the main class is a Sprite. Do you know how to add mx.controls.SWFLoader; to an ActionScript project?